# Android checkbox disabled but says enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewmodel, android-checkbox

I didn't want to create a question for this, but I can't figure out what's happening.

I have a checkbox where the enabled state is bound to a variable, `checkboxEnabled` in a ViewModel.  This variable is set to `true`, but the checkbox is somehow disabled.

Debugging steps:

- When I get the enabled state of the checkbox view from my fragment in `OnResume`, it also says `true`, even though the checkbox is clearly disabled.
- When I get the enabled state of the checkbox view in an onClickListener of another view, it does say `false`. However, the `checkboxEnabled` variable in my ViewModel is still `true` here.
- If I enable the checkbox in `onViewCreated`, it is still disabled.
- I've tried working with different bindings between the xml and `MyViewModel`, none of which seem to work, so it might be an issue with the databinding.

Why is my checkbox disabled if I don't set `checkboxEnabled` to false anywhere in my code?  Could it just be an issue linking the view model with the xml?

fragment_my.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyFragment">
    
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type=".MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:checked="@={viewModel.checkboxChecked}"
            android:enabled="@{viewModel.checkboxEnabled}"
            android:text="This is a checkbox" />

         <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/start_button"
            android:layout_below="@id/checkbox" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

MyFragment.kt:

```
class MyFragment() : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    private var _binding: FragmentMyBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java )
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        _binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val checkbox = view.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
        checkbox.isEnabled = true // doesn't stay enabled

        startButton = view.findViewById(R.id.start_button)

        startButton.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Checkbox enabled", "${checkbox.isEnabled}") // logs `false`
            Log.d("ViewModel checkbox enabled", "${viewModel.checkboxEnabled}") // logs `true`
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        val checkbox = activity?.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.checkbox)
        Log.d("Resumed", "${checkbox?.isEnabled}") // logs `true`
    }
}
```

And MyViewModel.kt:

```
class SensorGnssFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    var checkboxChecked = false
    var checkboxEnabled = true

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to pass the `viewModel` object to the layout with data binding like that `_binding.viewModel = viewModel`

Also, I'm confused with using `onCreate` and `onCreateView`, you can unify them to guarantee that `viewModel`  is initialized and passed to the layout.
So, update the `onCreateView` to be like that..

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java )
        _binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        _binding.viewModel = viewModel 
        return binding.root
    }
```

Another trick can help..
Try to replace the Boolean variables in the `viewModel` with `ObservableBoolean` to be:
`val checkboxEnabled : ObservableBoolean = ObservableBoolean()`

So, If you want to change check/enable the check box, just set and unset the observable object like that..

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewModel.checkboxEnabled.set(true)
    }
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! Way too much time debugging for just forgetting to set `binding.viewModel`

Comment: @DanielCJacobs  You're welcome.